# How to eliminate a whirring noise in Linux Yocto?

Tags: linux, pulse-audio

I am working with an Intel Edison board that has Linux Yocto. I have this issue of whirring noise when I try to record voice with a microphone. My microphone works fine with Windows. I tried to search for mic settings in alsamixer, but I could not find anything. What to do?